# Why are objects' values captured inside function calls?

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to pop up an alert with the number of the image when you click it:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    $("#img" + i).click(
        function () { alert(i); }
    );
}
```

You can see it not working at http://jsfiddle.net/upFaJ/. I know that this is because all of the click-handler closures are referring to the same object `i`, so every single handler pops up "10" when it's triggered.

However, when I do this, it works fine:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    (function (i2) {
        $("#img" + i2).click(
            function () { alert(i2); }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/v4sSD/.

Why does it work? There's still only one `i` object in memory, right? Objects are always passed by reference, not copied, so the self-executing function call should make no difference. The output of the two code snippets should be identical. So why is the `i` object being copied 10 times? Why does it work?

I think it's interesting that this version [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/vfwnU/):

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    (function () {
        $("#img" + i).click(
            function () { alert(i); }
        );
    })();
}
```

It seems that the passing of the object as a function parameter makes all the difference.

---

EDIT: OK, so the previous example can be explained by primitives (`i`) being passed by value to the function call. But what about this example, which uses real objects?

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var toggler = $("<img/>", { "src": "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/cross.png" });
    toggler.click(function () { toggler.attr("src", "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/tick.png"); });
    $("#container").append(toggler);
}
```

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/Zpwku/

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var toggler = $("<img/>", { "src": "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/cross.png" });
    (function (t) {
        t.click(function () { t.attr("src", "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/tick.png"); });
        $("#container").append(t);
    })(toggler);
}
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/YLSn6/

Comment: In one sentence: because the immediately invoked function takes the current `i` value and puts it in its *own* local variable (it copies the value), and since you have it in a loop, you'll generate 10 *separate* functions each with its own local variable which all store different values.

Comment: Small correction: not local variable, but argument, which is effectively the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the answers are correct in that passing an object as a function parameter breaks a closure and thus allow us to assign things to functions from within a loop. But I'd like to point out **why** this is the case, and it's not just a special case for closures.

You see, the way javascript passes parameters to functions is a bit different form other languages. Firstly, it seems to have two ways of doing it depending on weather it's a primitive value or an object. For primitive values it *seems* to pass by value and for objects it *seems* to pass by reference.

### How javascript passes function arguments

Actually, the real explanation of what javascript does explains both situations, as well as why it breaks closures, using just a single mechanism.

What javascript does is actually it passes parameters **by copy of reference**. That is to say, it creates another reference to the parameter and passes that new reference into the function.

### Pass by value?

Assume that all variables in javascript are references. In other languages, when we say a variable is a reference, we expect it to behave like this:

```
var i = 1;
function increment (n) { n = n+1 };
increment(i); // we would expect i to be 2 if i is a reference
```

But in javascript, it's not the case:

```
console.log(i); // i is still 1
```

That's a classic pass by value isn't it?

### Pass by reference?

But wait, for objects it's a different story:

```
var o = {a:1,b:2}
function foo (x) {
    x.c = 3;
}
foo(o);
```

If parameters were passed by value we'd expect the `o` object to be unchanged but:

```
console.log(o); // outputs {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

That's classic pass by reference there. So we have two behaviors depending on weather we're passing a primitive type or an object.

### Wait, what?

But wait a second, check this out:

```
var o = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
function bar (x) {
    x = {a:2,b:4,c:6}
}
bar(o);
```

Now see what happens:

```
console.log(o); // outputs {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

What! That's not passing by reference! The values are unchanged!

Which is why I call it **pass by copy of reference**. If we think about it this way, everything makes sense. We don't need to think of primitives as having special behavior when passed into a function because objects behave the same way. If we try to modify the object the variable points to then it works like pass by reference but if we try to modify the reference itself then it works like pass by value.

This also explains why closures are broken by passing a variable as a function parameter. Because the function call will create another reference that is not bound by the closure like the original variable.

### Epilogue: I lied

One more thing before we end this. I said before that this unifies the behavior of primitive types and objects. Actually no, primitive types are still different:

```
var i = 1;
function bat (n) { n.hello = 'world' };
bat(i);
console.log(i.hello); // undefined, i is unchanged
```

I give up. There's no making sense of this. It's just the way it is.

Comment: Really nice explanation! Especially the distillation of all the weirdness: "If we try to modify the object the variable points to then it works like pass by reference but if we try to modify the reference itself then it works like pass by value."

Comment: Nice explanation indeed. Regarding the epilogue: that doesn't work even without functions. You did not lie. Or did you...? o_O

Comment: Just to add to that deceze said: when you handle a primitive as an Object (calling a method on it, adding a property, etc.), a new *temporary* object is created around it, and discarded right after it's used. That's why the code on the epilogue won't work even without the function.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That actually makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are *calling a function*, passing it a *value*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(i);
}
```

You expect this to alert different values, right? Because you are passing the *current value of `i`* to `alert`.

```
function attachClick(val) {
    $("#img" + val).click(
        function () { alert(val); }
    );
}
```

With this function, you'd expect it to alert whatever `val` was passed into it, right? That also works when calling it in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    attachClick(i);
}
```

This:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (val) {
        $("#img" + val).click(
            function () { alert(val); }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

is just an inline declaration of the above. You are declaring an anonymous function with the same characteristics as `attachClick` above and you call it immediately. The act of passing a *value* through a *function parameter* breaks any references to the `i` variable.

Comment: That's almost the same thing I was going say. The key question is when the `i` pointer is dereferenced: while the loop is iterating or later.

Comment: But doesn't this show that references, not values, are passed through function parameters? `function toFive (a) { a = 5; } var b = 4; toFive(b);` After that, b is 5. So the value 4 isn't being passed through to toFive, the object reference is.

Comment: Also, in the first and second examples, alert alerts the correct value because i is still the value you expect at the moment that the alert is dispatched. It's not because of a special value-passing property of the function call.

Comment: @Brian And how do you know what exactly `alert` is doing? It *could* be executing the actual alert later! It's not visible what it does behind the scenes.

Comment: @BrianGordon Why do you think that b will be 5 in your example? Numbers are primitives, and primitives are unmutable. Hence, any changes made to them results in a new value.
Javascript *always* passes by value and has no notion of passing by reference.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that primitive objects are passed differently from normal ones. It all makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Wait a second, there's also a difference when you're dealing with real objects, not just primitives. See http://jsfiddle.net/YLSn6/ (working) and http://jsfiddle.net/Zpwku/ (non working). How do you explain that?

Comment: @BrianGordon: The way I explain it to my co workers is that in javascript, parameters are always passed by **copy**. For primitive types it's **copy of value** and for objects it's **copy of reference**. Yes, I know, **real** pass-by-value is different from this (and real pass-by-reference is again different). So, it's pass by copy (which, before this javascript madness was simply called pass by value)

Comment: Come to think of it, none of the answers here say exactly what I'm saying. I guess I should make the above comment an answer.

Comment: @BrianGordon : in reference to the jQuery object example... during the `for` loop, the `toggler` variable is set each iteration, creating 5 distinct jQuery objects.  However, because each one is defined in the same function scope, each new definition overrides the last.  With the closure added, you maintain a reference to each unique object.

Comment: @madlee Well said, I was confused there with your array example for a second. In your case, you only ever have one `i` array. If you create a new array each iteration, it works as well: http://jsfiddle.net/VRKaS/.

Answer (score 2):

upvoted deceze's answer, but thought I'd try a simpler explanation.  The reason the closure works is that variables in javascript are *function scoped*.  The closure creates a new scope, and by passing the value of `i` in as a parameter, you are defining a local variable `i` in the new scope.  without the closure, all of the click handlers you define are in the same scope, using the same `i`.  the reason that your last code snippet *doesn't* work is because there is no local `i`, so all click handlers are looking to the nearest parent context with `i` defined.

I think the other thing that might be confusing you is this comment

> Objects are always passed by reference, not copied, so the self-executing function call should make no difference.

this is true for objects, but not *primitive* values (numbers, for example).  This is why a new local `i` can be defined.  To demonstrate, if you did something weird like wrapping the value of i in an array, the closure would *not* work, because arrays are passed by reference.

```
// doesn't work
for(var i=[0]; i[0]<10; i[0]++) {
    (function (i2) {
        $("#img" + i2[0]).click(
            function () { alert(i2[0]); }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, there is only one value of `i` and it's the one used in the `for` loop.  This, all event handlers will show the value of `i` when the `for` loop ends, not the desired value.

In the second example, the value of `i` at the time the event handler is installed is copied to the `i2` function argument and there is a separate copy of that for each invocation of the function and thus for each event handler.

So, this:

```
(function (i2) {
    $("#img" + i2).click(
        function () { alert(i2); }
    );
 })(i);
```

Creates a new variable `i2` that has it's own value for each separate invocation of the function.  Because of closures in javascript, each separate copy of `i2` is preserved for each separate event handler - thus solving your problem.

In the third example, no new copy of `i` is made (they all refer to the same `i` from the `for` loop) so it works the same as the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 and Code 3 didn't work because `i` is a variable and values are changed in each loop. At the end of loop `10` will be assigned to `i`.

For more clear, take a look at this example,

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {

}

alert(i)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/t4Ur5/

You can see I put a `alert` after the loop and it will show show `alert` box with value `10`.

This is what happening to Code 1 and Code 3.

Answer (score 0):

Run the next example:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
     $("#img" + i).click(
          function () { alert(i); }
     );
}

i++;
```

You'll see that now, `11` is being alerted.
Therefore, you need to avoid the reference to `i`, by sending it as a function parameter, by it's value. You have already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that the other answers didn't mention is why this example that I gave in the question doesn't work:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var toggler = $("<img/>", { "src": "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/cross.png" });
    toggler.click(function () { toggler.attr("src", "http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/tick.png"); });
    $("#container").append(toggler);
}
```

Coming back to the question months later with a better understanding of JavaScript, the reason it doesn't work can be understood as follows:

1. The `var toggler` declaration is hoisted to the top of the function call. All references to `toggler` are to the same actual identifier.
2. The closure referenced in the anonymous function is the same (not a shallow copy) of the one containing `toggler`, which is being updated for each iteration of the loop.

#2 is quite surprising. This alerts "5" for example:

```
var o;
setTimeout(function () { o = {value: 5}; }, 100);
setTimeout(function () { alert(o.value) }, 1000);
```