# Argument's scope and object mutability in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, mutability

I've been given the following dummy assignment to learn about scope and mutability in JavaScript:

> For this exercise, write two functions, reverseArray and reverseArrayInPlace. The first, reverseArray, takes an array as argument and produces a new array that has the same elements in the inverse order. The second, reverseArrayInPlace, does what the reverse method does: it modifies the array given as argument in order to reverse its elements. Neither may use the standard reverse method.

I coded the reverseArray function successfully and wanted to reuse it for the reverseArrayInPlace function.  I coded 3 versions of the function and I really don't understand why some work, and some others don't.  I would appreciate any explanation about this javascript behavior.  (I know there are other ways to solve the reverseArrayInPlace but I want to know why my approach is not working).

```
// Reverses an array given as argument and returns it as a NEW array.
function reverseArray(myArray){
    var reversedArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        reversedArray.unshift(myArray[i]);
    }
    return reversedArray;
}

/*
    Reverse the original array in place
*/

// DOESN'T WORK
function reverseArrayInPlace1(myArray){
     myArray = reverseArray(myArray);
}

// DOESN'T WORK
function reverseArrayInPlace2(myArray){
    var original = [];
    for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        original[i]=myArray[i];
    }
     myArray = reverseArray(original);
}

// WORKS
function reverseArrayInPlace3(myArray){
    var original = [];
    for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        original[i]=myArray[i];
    }
     var newArray = reverseArray(original);
     for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i]=newArray[i];
    }
}

miArreglo = ["a", "b", "c", "d" ];
console.log("MyArray: ", miArreglo);

arregloRever=reverseArray(miArreglo);
console.log("Reversed using reverseArray: ", arregloRever);

reverseArrayInPlace1(miArreglo);
console.log("Reversed using reverseArrayInPlace1: ",miArreglo);

reverseArrayInPlace2(miArreglo);
console.log("Reversed using reverseArrayInPlace2: ",miArreglo);

reverseArrayInPlace3(miArreglo);
console.log("Reversed using reverseArrayInPlace3: ",miArreglo);
```

Comment: See this for an explanation of why the "doesn't work" parts don't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506398/why-are-objects-values-captured-inside-function-calls/13508654#13508654

Answer (score 3):

Your `reverseArrayInPlace1` and `reverseArrayInPlace2` don't work because arguments are passed by value in JavaScript. `myArray` is local to the function and reassigning it does not affect the caller.

You could take the opposite approach to your code reuse and implement `reverseArray` in terms of `reverseArrayInPlace`. You would copy the input array, reverse the copy in place, and return it. (You can copy an array by calling `arr.slice()`)

Comment: This doesn't explain why the 3rd approach works.  If arguments where passed by value, the global object wouldn't be modified using the argument "myArray".

Comment: The argument is passed by value. That doesn't mean the array is copied. Both values still reference the original array, so `myArray[i]` modifies the array's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function, `myArray` is a variable that refers to the original array, so any changes you make to the elements, for example

```
myArray[i] = x;
```

will change the original. But if you set the `myArray` *variable* to something, then the original array is taken out of scope, and you are only setting the local variable to the reversed array. [@dwickern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464776/1079573) gives you the right idea for fixing your code.