# How to change a object by function

Tags: javascript

In one task I have to change a object by deliver it to a function. it is almost like this:

```js
function change(obj) {
 return {
    fn1: function() {
        obj['three'] = 3;
    },   
    fn2: function() {      
        obj = {'four':4};      
    }
};
}

var obj = {'one':1,'two':2};
console.log(obj); // output 'Object {one=1, two=2}'
var temp = change(obj);
temp.fn1(); 
console.log(obj); //  output 'Object { one=1,  two=2,  three=3}'
temp.fn2();
console.log(obj); //  output 'Object { one=1,  two=2,  three=3}'
```

fn1 is for changing one of the object's value. As you can see, it intends to  set obj[three] to 3 and it works well.

fn2 is for replacing the object of another one. The obj should only contain 'four':4 after the execution。 however it didn't work.

Then I check the value of the obj inside fn2:

```
 ...
    fn2: function() {
      console.log('before fn2',obj);
      obj = {'four':4};
      console.log('after fn2', obj);
    }
};
...
```

The output is:

```
'before fn2 Object{one=1,two=2,three=3}'
'after fn2 Object{four=4}'
```

So it did work inside the fn2. I get confused that fn2 fails while fn1 works. How to fix it?

Comment: With the second function, you are changing the assignment of the local variable `obj` from it's original reference and assigning it to a new object. Same base problem as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930560/scope-in-javascript-acting-weird/30930727#30930727

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, arguments are passed by value, though that value often has pointer-like semantics. When you run `obj['three'] = 3;`, you are not rebinding the variable `obj`; you are merely changing a property of the object that `obj` currently holds. On the other hand, when you reassign `obj`, you are changing the *variable* `obj`, not the object that the variable used to hold. You cannot achieve your desired semantics in JavaScript; the best you can do would be to delete all properties of `obj` and copy over whatever properties you want to be on it.