# Explain how the code works

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

Consider the following node module. It spawns a sleep process for specified number of seconds and returns its PID. It fires the provided callback when the process exits.

```
//module.js    
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                                                               
function run(delay, cb) {                                                                                                   
    var args = [delay];                                                                                                     
    var process = spawn('sleep', args);                                                                                     

    (function(process, cb) {                                                                                                
        process.on('close', (code, signal) => {                                                                             
            cb(process.pid);                                                                                                
        });                                                                                                                 
    })(process, cb);                                                                                                        

    return process.pid;                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                           

module.exports = {                                                                                                          
    run: run                                                                                                                
}
```

The test code calls the module three times and saves the pids along with distinct strings to differentiate the callbacks.

```
var sleep = require("module");                                                                               
var pids = {};                                                                                                              

var cb = function(pid) {                                                                                                    
    console.log(pids[pid]);                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                           

pids[sleep.run(1, cb)] = 'cb1';                                                                                             
pids[sleep.run(2, cb)] = 'cb2';                                                                                             
pids[sleep.run(3, cb)] = 'cb3';
```

The code works perfectly and the output is:

```
cb1
cb2
cb3
```

My confusion stems from the fact that the code works perfectly even without the closure in the module, like so:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                                                            
function run(delay, cb) {                                                                                                
    var args = [delay];                                                                                                  
    var process = spawn('sleep', args);                                                                                  

    //(function(process, cb) {                                                                                           
        process.on('close', (code, signal) => {                                                                          
            cb(process.pid);                                                                                             
        });                                                                                                              
    //})(process, cb);                                                                                                   

    return process.pid;                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                        

module.exports = {                                                                                                       
    run: run                                                                                                             
}
```

I didn't expect the code to run without the closure. What would be the value of process when the first/second callback is called? Would it not be the value of the third process?

Comment: All calls to `run()` create a new closure with its own `process` variable and a new inner arrow function that can access it.

Comment: In the way it is written, there is no need for it....

Comment: Your confusion may stem from your misuse of terminology. In both the first and second versions of code you've created closures. The first version is a closure between the event handler and the anonymous function (the IIFE) and the second version is a closure between the event handler and the `run()` function

Comment: See my answer to this question to understand the difference between "closures" and what you think you're trying to do in the first version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414659/bind-a-changing-variable-in-function-i-want-a-name/40414915#40414915

Answer (score 0):

The function `(code, signal) => { cb(process.pid); }` is still a closure in your module. The scope over which it closes is provided by the `run` function (and contains the variables `delay`, `cb`, `args` and `process`), not the IIFE (whose scope only contained the `process` and `cb` variables that were shadowing the ones from `run`).