# How do you assign a value inside a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I expected the first console.log to be [0,10,20,30] and the second to be [0,100,20,30]:

```js
var arr = [0,10,20,30]
console.log(arr)
arr.forEach(each)
console.log(arr)

function each(data,index) {
   if (index === 1) {
      data = 100 // This isn't assigned to arr[1]
   }
}
```

Comment: arr[index] = 100. You can't assign to an array's index without the array.

Comment: Regardless weather it's forEach or any function this can never happen in javascript because it never pass by reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506398/why-are-objects-values-captured-inside-function-calls/13508654#13508654

Comment: `forEach` doesn't do the change inline. You have to use map for achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value to a local variable. For assigning to the actual index, you need the array and the index, the parameter two and three of the callback API of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var arr = [0,10,20,30]
console.log(arr)
arr.forEach(each)
console.log(arr)

function each(data,index, array) {
   if (index === 1) {
      array[index] = 100;
   }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```